# Не удается найти шаблон страницы создания задачи

Tags: битрикс

Пытаюсь отредактировать шаблон страницы создания задачи, расположенной по адресу: company/personal/user/1/tasks/task/edit/0/, но не удается его найти. Подскажите, каким образом можно находить шаблоны соответствующих страниц?

Answer (score 0):

Удалось найти описание компонентов модуля task https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/tasks/index.php Соответствующий шаблон хранится по пути: "bitrix\components\bitrix\tasks.task\templates.default\template.php".